# For Updated Android studio 4.2 :New Version Database Inspector lead my app crash when debug and open the DatabseInspector

Tags: android-studio-4.2

As the Title Show , New version database Inpector Will lead my app crash and Only show this:
For security reasons offline mode is disabled when the process being inspected does not correspond to the project open in studio or when the project has been generated from a prebuilt apk.
if restart and noever open the database tab .it was nomal . this problem Temporarily only happens on Huawei phones

Comment: this problem is nomal in version4.1

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? It's annoying and brakes normal behavior when testing on a real device.

Comment: I had update version 4.2.2,but it was no improve until now，if you still want to use huawei,you need to stop the datebase in backgroud ，otherwise you will alawts on Crash